# How do I copy a directory in Ant without deleting existing files in the destination directory?

Tags: ant, build, copy, build-process

I have the following file structure:

- FolderToBeCopied

  - folder1

    - somefile1
    - somefile2

I am copying FolderToBeCopied to a location which already contains files:

- DestinationFolder

  - folder1

    - anotherfile1
    - anotherfile2

I copy using the following in my Ant build script:

```xml
<copy overwrite="true" todir="DestinationFolder">
            <fileset dir="FolderToBeCopied" includes="**">
            </fileset>
        </copy>
```

However, when I run the build script, it copies the files somefile1 and somefile2 to folder1 at the destination, but deletes the files already in folder1 (ie. anotherfile1, anotherfile2). Is there a way to prevent it deleting files already in the destination folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Locate the `delete` element in your build script which deletes `DestinationFolder` and delete it.

[`copy` doesn't delete](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html). `overwrite` only means "copy even if the target is older than the source".

Comment: another possibility is the destinationFolder was not there in the first place. Then it can let one think it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent deletion of existing files in the destination folder, you could make a backup appending a timestamp to the filenames:

```
<project name="demoSO" basedir=".">

   <tstamp>
    <format property="touch.time" pattern="yyMMddHHmmssSSS"/>
  </tstamp>

  <target name="copyMyFiles">
    <copy todir="DestinationFolder" includeemptydirs="false">
      <fileset dir="FolderToBeCopied">
      </fileset>
      <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*-${touch.time}"/>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```